# AR app - detect round objects

Tags: iphone, ios4, augmented-reality, metaio

I am a total newbie wanting to develop an AR app and identify round objects. Can someone help me with some good frameworks and tutorials to use them?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You Should GPUImage give a try: https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage if the round objects has a specific color. If the only attribute of the object is that its rounden, it would be difficult to find the object in a image, with AR technic

Comment: I want to identify wheel caps, when the phone is pointed to one. :P

Comment: oh okay, i think it is very complex to realize the app, because you haven't any specific marker

Comment: Hmm.. I'll check up the feasibility aspect. Thanks fr the links though!:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try metaio: http://www.metaio.com